# Symfony2 controller static variable

Tags: symfony, static, controller

In one of my controllers, I have some static variables and two actions:

```
class ChooseController extends Controller
{
    private static $wholedata = array();                          

    private static $currentdata = array();                            

    private static $wholenum = 0; 

    private static $currentnum = 0;  

    public function choosefirstAction()
    {
         $company = $this->getUser()->getCompany();
         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

         self::$wholedata = $this->getDoctrine()
         ->getRepository('NeejobCompanyBundle:Selected')->findBy(
            array("company" => $company),
            array("job" => 'ASC')
         );

        self::$wholenum = count(self::$wholedata);
        self::$currentdata = array_slice(self::$wholenum, 0, 3);
        self::$currentnum = 3;

        return new response(json_encode(self::$currentdata));
    }

    public function choosemoreAction()
    {
        //... 
        return new response(self::$wholenum);
    }
}
```

I still have `$wholenum = 0`, which is supposed to be 3 or larger. How should I handle the problem?

Comment: Could you add the changes that you made to "this data" that's the most important part.

Comment: I have already copyed my codes in it. I tried some test code, all failed...@Sparkup

Comment: `$wholenum` isn't being stored anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send the data in `choosefirstAction` your class values are no longer set, you need to store them somewhere (i.e. in the session) :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class ChooseController extends Controller
{
    public function choosefirstAction()
    {
        $company = $this->getUser()->getCompany(); 
        $doc = $this->getDoctrine();


        $wholedata = $doc->getRepository('...Bundle:Selected')->findBy(
            array('company' => $company),
            array('job'     => 'ASC')
        );

        $wholenum = count($wholedata);
        $currentdata = array_slice($wholenum, 0, 3);
        $currentnum  = 3;

        $session = $this->get('session');
        $session->set('wholenum',  $wholenum);

        return new JsonResponse($currentdata);
    }

    public function choosemoreAction()
    {
        $wholenum = $this->get('session')->get('wholenum');

        return new response($wholenum);
    }
}
```

More on sessions in symfony [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html)